# CUDA texture object problems

Tags: c++, cuda

I seem to be having some difficulty in the use of texture objects in CUDA. I took the code from [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#texture-object-api) and simplified it and fleshed it out a bit. When I go to build it I get the error "type name is not allowed". It occurs on line 18 in my code, does anyone have any idea why that is the case?

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <texture_fetch_functions.h>
#include <cuda_texture_types.h>
#include <texture_indirect_functions.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <vector>

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

#define L 16384

__global__ void read(cudaTextureObject_t t, float *b){
    float offset = blockIdx.x + 0.5f;
    b[blockIdx.x] = tex2D<float>(t, offset, 0.5f);
}

int main(){
    //device memory and host memory allocation
    cudaChannelFormatDesc channelFormat = cudaCreateChannelDesc(32, 0, 0, 0, cudaChannelFormatKindFloat);
    cudaArray *dev_buff_a;
    float *dev_buff_b, *hst_buff, *print_buff;
    hst_buff = (float *)malloc(L * sizeof(float));
    print_buff = (float *)malloc(L * sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocArray(&dev_buff_a, &channelFormat, L, 1);
    cudaMalloc(&dev_buff_b, L * sizeof(float));
    for(int i = 0; i < L; i++){
        hst_buff[i] = 1.0f;
    }
    //
    cudaMemcpyToArray(dev_buff_a, 0, 0, hst_buff, L * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //creating the texture object
    //start with the resource descriptor
    cudaResourceDesc resource;
    memset(&resource, 0, sizeof(resource));
    resource.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
    resource.res.array.array = dev_buff_a;
    /*resource.res.linear.desc.f = cudaChannelFormatKindFloat;  //channel format
    resource.res.linear.desc.x = 32;    //bits per channel
    resource.res.linear.sizeInBytes = L * sizeof(float);*/

    //next, is the texture descriptor
    cudaTextureDesc texDesc;
    memset(&texDesc, 0, sizeof(texDesc));
    texDesc.readMode = cudaReadModeElementType;

    //to create the actual texture object
    cudaTextureObject_t tObj = 0;
    cudaCreateTextureObject(&tObj, &resource, &texDesc, NULL);

    //perform reading function
    dim3 block(1, 0, 0);
    dim3 grid(16384, 0, 0);
    read<<<grid, block>>>(tObj, dev_buff_b);

    //copy stuff over from dev_buff_b to print
    cudaMemcpy(print_buff, dev_buff_b, L * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    //print out the arrays and compare
    std::cout << "the original array was:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < L; i++){
        std::cout << "element " << i << "is: " << hst_buff[i] << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "the new array is:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < L; i++){
        std::cout << "element " << i << "is: " << print_buff[i] << "\n";
    }

    //destroy the texture object
    cudaDestroyTextureObject(tObj);
    //free device memory
    cudaFreeArray(dev_buff_a);
    cudaFree(dev_buff_b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this - your code compiles perfectly for me. What CUDA version and host compiler are you using?

Comment: I am compiling this in VS2012 on CUDA 5.5. The GPU I am running on is a Geforce GT 630M.

Comment: Also, I have attempted to compile the "Bindless Texture" sample program, and that compiled successfully. I feel like I am taking crazy pills...

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure to follow these two things:

- You're using Cuda 5.0 or newer
- Compiler settings are to compile only for devices of compute capability 3.0 or better ('-arch compute_30' flag for nvcc)

Texture objects are only available on these newer devices.

Comment: I am using CUDA 5.5 on a Geforce GT 630M. I am not entirely sure if the 630M is a Kepler GPU or not though...

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus says that it's not, so no texture objects can be used on this device.

Comment: So back to texture references I go?